# Object Array to Hash Table

Tags: javascript, ramda.js

Would like to convert (using Ramda)

```
var a = [{id: 1, name: 'one'}, {id: 2, name: 'two'},{id: 3, name: 'three'}]
```

into

```
var b = {1:'one', 2:'two', 3:'three'}
```

I'm very new to functional programming and I am open to any ideas.

What I think we must do is, use a reduce function starting with {} and then we want to add on each iteration the id and name of the current element to the hashtable. This is what I came up with which appears very wrong. Am I close?

```
var a = [{id: 1, name: 'one'}, {id: 2, name: 'two'},{id: 3, name: 'three'},{id: 4, name: 'four'} ]
var b = R.reduce(R.assoc(R.prop('id'), R.prop('name')), {}, a)
b
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many approaches to this that will work.  All the other correct answers helps show that.  I'll list a few of my own below.  But first,

### Why your approach isn't working

You try to do this:

```
R.reduce(R.assoc(R.prop('id'), R.prop('name')), {}, a)
```

It's clear what you're trying to do here.  The trouble is that `R.prop('id')` and `R.prop('name')` are functions.  `R.assoc` does not accept functions; it wants a String (Number will actually serve) and an arbitrary value.  So `assoc` will not work with these in this manner.

One attempt to clean this up is to recognize that functions can be thought of as *containers* of values.  In some -- perhaps surprising, but quite useful -- way, a function is a container of its return value.  [`R.lift`](https://ramdajs.com/docs/#lift) is meant to turn functions that work on values into ones that work on *containers* of values.  It works like this: `R.multiply` accepts numbers.  If we *lift* `multiply`, the resulting function accepts containers of numbers.  Like this:

```
R.lift(R.multiply)(Maybe.Just(5), Maybe.Just(3))  // Maybe.Just(15)
```

If we supply `lift(multiply)` with two functions, then we get back a function that returns the result of multiplying their return values:

```
const area = R.lift(R.multiply)(prop('width'), prop('height'))
area({width: 5, height: 3})
```

So perhaps we could update your technique with a `lift`:

```
R.reduce(R.lift(R.assoc)(R.prop('id'), R.prop('name'), identity), {}, a)
```

Unfortunately, this fails again.  The trouble this time is that `reduce` takes a binary callback, supplying both the accumulator and the current value.  But `R.prop('id')` and `R.prop('name')` don't recognize that.  They look for the relevant properties on the accumulator, which simply are not there.

We might still be able to fix this, but at this point, we'd be losing a great deal of the simplicity of this solution.  So let's look at other possibilities.

### Some solutions

#### Simple Reduce

Each of these two versions uses a simple `reduce` call, as your solution tried to do:

```
const convertToHash = reduce((acc, {id, name}) => merge(acc, {[id]: name}), {})
```

and

```
const convertToHash = reduce((acc, {id, name}) => ({...acc, [id]: name}), {})
```

They are much the same.  Both create disposable objects on each iteration.  In the first one, you could replace `R.merge` with `Object.assign` without any real issues, as the resulting mutation is internal to the function.  The second one seems slightly more elegant, but it rebuilds the entire accumulator on each iteration.  As the engine optimization for ES6 proceeds, this will likely eventually not be a performance problem, but it might be right now, especially if this is in performance-critical code.

#### Using `zipWith`

Ramda's `zip` functions take two lists and combine them, position by position, into a single list.  [`R.zipWith`](https://ramdajs.com/docs/#zipWith) accepts a function used to combine the two elements into one.  Here we use [`R.objOf`](https://ramdajs.com/docs/#objOf), which turns a name and a value into a single-property object.  (`objOf('foo', 42) //=> {foo: 42}`.):

```
const convertToHash = compmose(mergeAll, lift(zipWith(objOf))(pluck('id'), pluck('name')))
```

As above, we use `lift` to make this `zipWith(objOf)` work with functions.  That results in something like `[{"1": "one"}, {"2": "two"}, {"3": "three"}]`, which we then pass to [`R.mergeAll`](https://ramdajs.com/docs/#mergeAll) to create a single object.

#### Using `props` and `fromPairs`

This solutions uses [`R.props`](https://ramdajs.com/docs/#props) and [`R.fromPairs`](https://ramdajs.com/docs/#fromPairs).  `fromPairs` accepts a list of name-value pairs (as two-element arrays) and turns them into a single object.  `props` pulls the named properties into a stand-alone array.  [`Mapping`](https://ramdajs.com/docs/#map) this over the original list give us the input to `fromPairs`:

```
const convertToHash = compose(fromPairs, map(props(['id', 'name'])))
```

Although I'm fond of the `zipWith` solution, and would use it if its output was what I wanted, having to add the `mergeAll`, makes it harder to comprehend at a glance.  And so this solution wins in my mind as the best Ramda choice.

Comment: This has really helped me understand the problem. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You could achieve this by the following:

```
 var a = [{id: 1, name: 'one'}, {id: 2, name: 'two'},{id: 3, name: 'three'}]

 var b = R.reduce((dict, item) => ({ ...dict, [ item.id ] : item.name }), {}, a)
```

This approach uses es6 syntax to add keys (named via `item.id`) with value (`item.name`) to your resulting dictionary, during each iteration of the reduction.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a pipeline ([R.pipe](https://ramdajs.com/docs/#pipe)) to convert your array of objects to a hash:

1. Get the values of each ([R.map](https://ramdajs.com/docs/#map)) objects' properties ([R.props](https://ramdajs.com/docs/#props)).
2. Convert the array of pairs to an object ([R.fromPairs](https://ramdajs.com/docs/#fromPairs)).

```js
const a = [{id: 1, name: 'one'}, {id: 2, name: 'two'},{id: 3, name: 'three'}];

const convertToHash = (props) => 
  R.pipe(
    R.map(R.props(props)),
    R.fromPairs
  );
  
const result = convertToHash(['id', 'name'])(a);  
  
console.log(result);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ramda/0.25.0/ramda.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using this code:

```
   var a = [{id: 1, name: 'one'}, {id: 2, name: 'two'},{id: 3, name: 'three'}]
    R.map(i=> {
      var n = []
      n[R.keys(i)[0]] = i.name
      return n
    },a)
```

Comment: Generally, answers are much more helpful if they include an explanation of what the code is intended to do, and why that solves the problem without introducing others.

Answer (score 0):

when using es6 you can get a more flexible solution

```js
let a = [{id: 1, name: 'one'}, {id: 2, name: 'two'},{id: 3, name: 'three'}];
let out = a.reduce((acc, {id, name}) => {
  acc[id] = name;
  return acc;
}, {});
console.log(out)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can loop your initial array and assign to new object:

```js
var a = [{id: 1, name: 'one'}, {id: 2, name: 'two'},{id: 3, name: 'three'}];
var new_a = {};

a.forEach(function(e) {
    new_a[e.id] = e.name;
});

console.log(new_a);
```

Comment: This answer is crying out for a `reduce`!